# Knative installation: Can't pull "gke.gcr.io/istio/proxy_init:1.2.10-gke.1"

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, knative, knative-serving

I am trying to install Knative on my GKE cluster. I followed the [Knative website](https://knative.dev/docs/install/knative-with-gke/) to do it. However, Knative Serving can't be installed due to the following error:

```
Failed to pull image "gke.gcr.io/istio/proxy_init:1.2.10-gke.1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: manifest for gke.gcr.io/istio/proxy_init:1.2.10-gke.1 not found: manifest unknown: Failed to fetch "1.2.10-gke.1" from request "/v2/istio/proxy_init/manifests/1.2.10-gke.1".
```

Do you know how to solve this ?

Regards,

Comment: Change it to use public `istio/proxy_init:1.2.10` image from dockerhub, does this solve your issue?

Comment: i don't try to pull directly this image. It is by using commands in the website like "kubectl apply --selector knative.dev/crd-install=true \
--filename https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.12.0/serving.yaml .."

Comment: are you using a private cluster?

Comment: I am using GKE on GCP